# Google navigation Intent disable satellite view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation, routes

In my application I have an Intent which have to open Google navigation, and set the route from my current location to the given longitude and latitude.
This works al perfect with the following code:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + item.getNavigateTo() + "&mode=w")
```

But when the Google navigation app is opened, it is in satellite view. Is there an option to disable the satellite view in Google navigation without opening the settings of the app?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is outside of your own application this is not posible.